# how to get Coreference Resolution annotation in stanford core nlp toolkit?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford Corenlp toolkit to annotate a text. I tried to use the code provided here : http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/
and it works well. The problem is when i want to use **Co-reference Resolution tool embedded in coreNLP toolkit**. It does not work. i used the code that were published by stanford nlp group. code is here below:

```
public class CorefExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Annotation document = new Annotation("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii. He is the president. Obama was elected in 2008.");

  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  pipeline.annotate(document);
  System.out.println("---");
  System.out.println("coref chains");
  for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values())          {     
     System.out.println("\t"+cc);
  }
  for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class))
  {
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("mentions");
    for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("\t"+m);
     }
   }
  }
}
```

but when i want to run these codes, i got null,this line : "**sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)**"
always **return null**, while i am sure that toolkit has annotaed corefrence mentions. 
I really mixed up. what is the solution? how can i receive the coref annottaion in java code?

Comment: Why do you need to get the mentions coreferenced for each sentence? When I had to deal with it I just used the info from the CorefChainAnnotation and matched it to the sentence information checking the token indices given in the chains.

Comment: Tx. I mean i just need to determine absolute mentions such as "obama and he". For instance if we have: "Obama was born in USA. He is a president. He is elected in 2008" , chains are: /obama & USA/ ,/Obama &  he/ ,/President  & 2008/. How did you filter it? I thouhgt there must be an option to give it to me. ( as  corenlp online demo http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/ facilitated to this feature!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run the sample code on the coref page with the latest stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar it runs to completion, so I am not seeing the null issue you are talking about.

Make sure to use the latest jar available on the website, version 3.6.0

Update:

If you cut and paste the code on this page:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html

and put into a file called CorefExample.java then do:

```
javac -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*" CorefExample.java
java -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*:." CorefExample
```

You should see the mentions printed out.

We've updated the distribution, so also make sure you've downloaded it recently.

If you're still having problems we will have to figure out what is different from what I just described and your set up.  I just cut and paste the code and ran it as described above and I see the mentions printed out (I even added a sentence with no mentions to the sample text) and I get a list with the mentions (or empty list).  So you shouldn't be getting null if you're using that exact code with the latest jar.

It would be helpful to know how you're running the code so we can see what the difference is.

Comment: I've downloaded latest version (2015 V.3-6-0). When i use this code: "pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation,xmlout);" , corefernce set would be printed in my consol (here /Obama , he/  is printed!). Even using this code: "annotation.get(CorefCoreAnnotation.CorefChainAnnotation.class);" , it shows me whole chain dependencies in the sentence,NOT JUST MENTIONS. So only way to get mentions is: "annotation.get(CorefCoreAnnotation.CorefMentionAnnotation.class)". But as i told, it returns null value. I even tested it in different system with same result! :(

Comment: By the way make sure its sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotation.CorefMnetionAnnotation.class) ... each sentence contains a list of its mentions

Comment: The example class CorefExample on this page: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html should work if you use a version downloaded recently, so I am not sure why you wouldn't see mentions.  I see them printed out for me (for the example sentence in CorefExample.java).

Comment: NOW It works! I forget to add "mention tag"  to property!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with version 3.7.0, while using the coreference resolution with "**dcoref**" (deterministic approach) parameter instead "**coref**". I am not sure which packages you were importing while performing the coreference resolution and experiencing the error (not mentioned in the above code snippet), but I suppose the ones mentioned in [this](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html) example code.

In my case, I included the packages manually and didn't copy them from the example. Therefore, Intellij proposed that I use either

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
```

as in the example,

or:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
```

I chose the second option and this created the null error for me. Actually, not only was `sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)` null, but `document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class)` as well.